# My company was recently acquired, how do I tell them I willing to relocate

Tags: communication, job-offer

My current company has been acquired by another company. They want to take over my department to their headquarter. They only want to keep me until the end of October. However, I'm willing to relocate to their headquarter.

1. Should I need to write the mail to tell them?
2. How to write the Mail?

Thanks,

Comment: What did your immediate superior say when you mentioned this?

Comment: I don't have a supervisor. He left the company.

Comment: If they wanted to retain you, they would have asked if you were willing to relocate.  Seems your position is probably redundant, and they don't need you.

Answer (score 17):

Contact whomever told you that they will be terminating your employment in October, who I assume is someone in Human Resources.  If it is not someone in Human Resources, then contact the person and cc your Human Resources contact.

A simple email such as the following would get the ball rolling.

> Dear PersonName,
>
> Per our communication on SomeDate, I understand my employment is to be
>   terminated at the end of October.  I also understand that this
>   termination coincides with the relocation of my current department to
>   NewLocation.  I would like to express my desire to stay with the
>   company, and relocate to NewLocation with my department. Please advise
>   the possibility of this relocation.
>
> Thank you for your time,
>
> Alex

If your notice of termination wasn't from HR, then cc'ing HR on this mail alerts them to the situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to tell them you are willing to relocate is in the cover letter of your application package.  You should send out a bunch of those to other companies too.